# Django page not loading form

Tags: html, django

I am developing a website in Django. On a home page, it has a navbar on which there are different sections of my website listed as a list items:
[image]

As shown in screen shot there is a login button on right top. when I click on login a Modal drops from top which has a login form.
[image]

This arrangement is working fine only for home page. If I go to some other tab in Navbar I only get empty modal.
[image]

This is my base.html where I am including header and footer and body section gets added as I extend base.html in respective pages.

> ```
> {% include "header.html" %}
>
> {% block body %}
> {% endblock %}
>
> {% include "footer.html" %}
> ```

I assume, How page loads form correctly because in the its view I pass form variable through context. Now, Since none other page knows what login form means it just renders empty modal. adding login form in every pages view would be too redundant. Is there any approach to go about it?

Here is my login view:

```
def custom_login(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        #User Login success
        username = req.POST['username']
        password = req.POST['password']
        user = authenticate (username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(req, user)
            return redirect('/login/settings/profile')
        else:
        #User Login Failure
            form = AuthenticationForm()
            args = {'loginForm':form, 'flash':'Invalid Combination of Username and Password'}
            return render(req,'login/login.html', args)
    else:
        if req.user.is_authenticated():
            return redirect('/login/settings/profile')
        else:   
            form = AuthenticationForm()
            args = {'loginForm':form}
            return render(req,'login/login.html',args)
```

And this is my header.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<nav class="navbar navbar nav-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">DabaKaka</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse"> 
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="/packages/">Packages</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
          <li class="user-name">{{user.first_name}}</li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"> 
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-User"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="/login/settings/personal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span> Account Settings</a></li>
              <li><a href="/login/logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

        {% else %}
          <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Login</a></li>
          <li><a href="/login/register">Register</a></li>
        {% endif %}
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <h4 class="modal-title">Enter Username and Password</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ loginForm|crispy }}
      <br>
      {% if flash %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">{{flash}} </div>
        <br>
      {% endif %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button><br><br>
      <p><small><a href="/login/resetpassword">Forgot Password or Username?</a></small></p>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  </div>
  </div>
```

And this is the Home page .

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block title %}
    <title>Login</title>
{% endblock %}
     .......Some contents......
{% block body %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: show your views and template.

Comment: @RohitChopra I have updated question to show templates and view

Answer (score 0):

You can use a RequestContext and a context processor to automatically adds variables in every template

```
from django.template import RequestContext, Context
#
#
#

def some_view(request):
    # some view content
    #
    return  render_to_response(template_name,locals(), RequestContext(request,processors=[master_vars]))

def master_vars(request):
    args = user_permissions(request.user)
    # add other vars to args dict
    args["loginForm"] = AuthenticationForm()
    # add more vars as you need
    #
    return args
```

Then you can use these vars in any template

`{{ loginForm|crispy }}`